# UI-Grid Exporter Issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using ui-grid and I'm using exporterfieldcallback to change the font color based on a color array, when exporting to pdf. It works fine for pdf, but when I export to csv, the data is not correct. Is there a flag or field set, when pdf or csv is selected, so I can differentiate between the two?  In the example below, when exporting to csv, this is in the csv file: "displayStatus = {text: displayText, color: 'red'};"
I'm hoping to do something like this:

```
`exporterfieldcallback: function(grid, row, col, value) {
     if (statusValue === displayValue) {
         if(exportFlag === 'pdf'){ // This is what I'm looking for!
             // When the pdf is rendered, the colors are perfect. 
             displayStatus = {text: displayText, color: 'red'};
         }else{
             displayStatus = displayText;
         }
     }
     return displayStatus; 
 }`
```

Then I can just exclude the export to csv from the custom formatting.

Comment: can you provide a simple example highlighting the issue. please create in jsfiddle and share the link

Answer (score 0):

I created an example in Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ef5ecLqSDMvotpamcpyf?p=preview. With the code below, the export to pdf works correctly on my local box. When you try to export to pdf it's not working correctly in plunker. The problem I'm having is when you export to csv, I get the error. I tried to modify the ui-grid.js and save it to my plunker, but I kept getting an error. This code needs to be added to line 18883 in ui-grid.js for this to export to pdf correctly. 
    `} else if (typeof(field.value) === 'object') 
        returnVal = field.value;`